# [WHM][CPANEL] xml-api - get_update_availability locks server

Tags: linux, cpanel

At random moments our Cpanel server completely hangs itself. We see huge spikes in load (150), disk io's and IO wait 100%

Finally I've identified the responsible processes and it seems that Cpanel/WHM executes a lot of these:

> xml-api - get_update_availability -json ./get_update_availability
>
> xml-api - get_current_lts_expiration_s -json ./get_current_lts_expiration_status

Killing them one by one unlocks the server and it starts running again.

Does anybody have a idea what this is and what causes the spawn of so many processes?

- CENTOS 7.3 x86_64 xen hvm
- cPanel & WHM 64.0 (build 18)
- also running csf/lfd